# Clean 301 .htaccess for Multiple Subs (not Wildcard)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there a more clean way to redirect a couple of Subdomains (105) besides of using for every subdomain this code? The Subdomains are having nothing in common.. So I am really at an dead end besides of that solution. That would be 200 lines code for all Subdomains :(

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nicefood.domain.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cellphones.domain.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^disaster.domain.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^germany.domain.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/ [R=301,L]
```

So it gets kind of messy in the .htaccess

Any other idea someone?

Comment: Is this for every subdomains or do you have some subdomains exception ?

Comment: I am very sorry that i had forgot to mention. YES, i do have exceptions, also a lot, more exceptions that sites to redirect. All in all there are ~500 Subdomains and at the moment it looks like that there are ~250-300 Subdomains i wish to redirect.

Comment: Do they have something similar that we could take into consideration ? Alphabetical order, or something else ? Otherwise, you will have to write a rule for each subdomain

Comment: Sadly they do not have something in common.
I had hoped that there might be a way that I could at least get all Subdomain that are to be redirected into one rule with a seperator or something like that. I had even tried to use it like
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nicefood.domain.tld$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cellphones.domain.tld$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^disaster.domain.tld$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^germany.domain.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/ [R=301,L]`
To avoid all duplicated lines, but it didn't worked out.

Comment: That's because it acts like an `AND` condition. If you want an `OR` condition, add a `[OR]` flag after each RewriteCond (except the last one). But if you want to use a separator, you can do it this way: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(nicefood|other|another|etc).domain.tld$`

Comment: That would be IMHO much better than my actual Solution. I know, or at least I remembered that there was something like the seperator, but I had really no idea how that was used. I am happy to get a decent html coding done, but with php/htaccess I am happy if i can copy together the pieces i need to get things done. Thank you very much for the example, I'll give it a shot...

Comment: I forgot to escape dots in the pattern i gave you. Instead it would be `^(nicefood|other|another|etc)\.domain\.tld$`

Comment: Thank you very much Justin lurman. This might be a very late reply, but indeed that seems to be the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in **single rule** like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```